# How to display only taxonomies of custom post type in a page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have created recipe as a custom post and types as a taxonomy.
In that taxonomy I have created vegetables and fruits as fields and I have 5 posts in each fields, but I need to display only vegetables and fruits in the page?

The below Query is what I currently use. It displays all posts.

```
<?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'recipe', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'recipe', 'posts_per_page' => 9 ) );
?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you fix your code? It was mangled. Do you just want to list the taxonomy terms? Or the posts in those terms?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [taxonomy query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), like this:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'recipe',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'types',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'vegetables', 'fruit' )
                 )
        )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```